# golang attach a socket to Stdin/Stdout

Tags: sockets, redirect, go, stdin, named-pipes

What is the best way to attach a socket to Stdin/Stdout. I know we can redirect the stdin/Stdout to any any file descriptor but how can we do the same with sockets. (like how socat works) ?

Comment: Where is the code written by you? Have you tried anything yet.

Comment: I have added something to open a pipe and set the fd of the pipe to terminal.MakeRaw() but looks like we cant do something like that with sockets.

Answer (score 2):

Well the socket types in Go implement the `io.Writer` interface, and `os.Stdin` implements the `io.Reader`, so my first guess would be to try out `bufio.Writer`. It would probably look something like:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    socket := getSocket() // left as an exercise for you to implement
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(socket)
    writer.ReadFrom(os.Stdin)
    // do something to determine when to stop
}
```

Comment: By creating a socket do you mean net.Dial() ? 

I need to attach the current terminal to the unix socket. - The other end of the socket is running agetty. Should I have to use the termios structure accomplish this?

Comment: @Harish `net.Dial` can open unix sockets: `net.Dial("unix", "/path/to/unix.sock")`